# Почему работает неправильно код?

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём проблема?
"Текстовый файл состоит не более чем из 1 200 000 символов X, Y, и Z. Определите максимальное количество идущих подряд символов, среди которых нет подстроки XZZY"
Файл не могу загрузить.

```py
f = open('24_3.txt').readline()
k = 1
m = 1
for i in range(1, len(f) - 1):
    if f[i] == 'X' and f[i + 1] == 'Z' and f[i + 2] == 'Z' and f[i + 3] == 'Y':
        k = 1
    else:
        k += 1
    m = max(m, k)
print(m)
```

Но выдаётся неправильный ответ

Comment: Что у вас конкретно не работает, не совсем понятно.

Comment: выдается неправильный ответ. Отличается от правильного на 2

Comment: Кто-ж Вас так файлы открывать учил

Comment: А как правильно?

Comment: мне нужно получить максимальное количество подряд идущих символов, среди которых нет XZZY

Comment: извините, ошибся, нужно найти максимальное количество идущих подряд символов, среди которых нет подстроки XZZY. Именно подстроки

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да это одно и то же задание из егэ, по сути

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спорить с тобой не буду, потому что ты по задачам 100% круче меня, поэтому удалю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно работать правильно:

```
with open('24.txt', 'r') as f:
    f = f.read()

my_list: list = list(map(len, f.split('XZZY')))
my_list[0], my_list[-1] = my_list[0] - 3, my_list[-1] - 3
print(max(my_list) + 6)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Можете пояснить немного, что в этом коде происходит?

Comment: Этот код не всегда работает правильно. Например на строке `X`.

Comment: у меня правильно сработал. А можно пояснение для каждой команды?

Comment: Он правильно сработал на конкретном файле. С тем же успехом сработает программа `print(<ожидаемый ответ>)`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Конкретно для такого подвида егэ задач он скорее всего будет правильно работать.

Comment: Что ЕГЭ плохо тестирует программу - это ясно. Если цель - сдать ЕГЭ, то ОК. А если цель решить задачу и понять решение, то ...

Comment: Моя цель понять алгоритм самого задания. И смочь написать программу для нахождения ответа. Для любой вариации такого задания

Comment: Поэтому я и хочу узнать пояснение для этого кода

Comment: @Krimer split - разбивает строку по символам XZZY, создавая подстроки и возвращая список этих подстрок. map  - применяет len, на каждый объект этого списка возвращая длину для каждой подстроки. list на map возвращает новый список где теперь есть только длина всех подстрок. А max возвращает максимальную длину из этого списка. +6, поскольку изначально разбивали на XZZY(Пояснение, XZZY стояли с обоих сторон максимальное подстроки, мы убираем один элемент, с обоих сторон и получаем 6).

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: немного не понял, зачем убирать с обеих сторон по одному элементу?

Comment: Приведу пример: XZZYZZZXZZY, если сделать сплит, то будет объект ZZZ,  правильный ответ на задачу это подстрока ZZYZZZXZZ, поскольку надо найти такую подстроку, чтобы в ней не было XZZY, а для этого надо убрать по X с края данной подстроки, то есть +3 с одой стороны и + 3 с другой

Comment: теперь понял, спасибо

Comment: Вторая функция в ответе ниже и правда немного лучше моей, в том плане, что она рассматривает случаи, когда строка максимальной длины находилась бы в конце или в начале. Сейчас отредактирую свой ответ на такой случай.

Answer (score 4):

То что происходит в функции `max_proper_substr` лучше всего нарисовать:

Точками обозначены последовательности символов в которых нет комбинации `XYYZ`.

> ```
> первая подстрока             третья подстрока
> |                            | 
> -------------                ------------------
> ..........XZZY..............XZZY............XZZY........
>            --------------------              -----------
>            |                                 |
>            вторая подстрока                  четвёртая
> ```

Подстроки свободные от `XZZY` обозначены пунктирными линиями. Как видите они перекрываются. Код ниже учитывает это:

```
def max_proper_substr(text):
    max_length = 0
    start = 0
    while True:
        end = text.find('XZZY', start)
        if end == -1:
            length = len(text) - start
            max_length = max(max_length, length)
            break
        length = end - start + 3
        max_length = max(max_length, length)
        start = end + 1
    return max_length
```

Читать файл тоже надо умеючи. В хвосте файла, скорее всего будет перевод строки, который надо убрать вызовом `strip`. Иначе он может быть зачтён в длину последней подстроки.

```
with open('24_3.txt') as f:
    text = f.read().strip()
```

Код выше правильно решает поставленную задачу при любых входных данных. То что в ЕГЭ только один тест и строка в середине позволяет срезать угол. Я срезать угол не стану, а покажу ещё одно правильное полное решение. Идея в том чтобы разбить текст на фрагменты, а затем увеличить длину фрагментов на шесть, если они внутри, и на три, если с краю. Код правильно сработает даже если фрагмент один:

```
def max_proper_substr2(text):
    lengths = [len(s) for s in text.split('XZZY')]
    lengths[0] -= 3
    lengths[-1] -= 3
    return 6 + max(lengths)
```

**P.S.** Константы `3` и `6` в коде заменяются на значения зависящие от длины "запрещённой" подстроки. Оба решения можно обобщить для любых "запрещённых" подстрок. Но не всё так просто.

*Упражение 1* Придумайте "запрещённую" строку для которой второе решение будет давать неправильные ответы.

*Упражение 2* Покажите что первое решение работает для любых "запрещённых" строк.

Comment: спасибо за подробное объяснение

Answer (score 1):

Не ответ

```
with open('24_3.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    text = file.read()
    # В вашем случае, скорее всего, так
    # Дальше ищем последовательньности
```